# Prefix and BindAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with using the prefix, seems like whenever I use the Bind, the entire viewmodel's objects gets set to null on post.

Atm I have:

```
[Bind(Prefix = "User", Include = "Firstname,Username,Lastname,Email")]UserAdminEditViewModel userobj
```

I've tried to use prefix "User." and "User_", only change is that only the "objuser" is null when I hover in debugmode.

My class looks like this:

```
public class UserAdminEditViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Usergroup> Usergroups { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

    public UserAdminEditViewModel() {}
}
```

But I can't get them to map to userobj.User.Firstname etc.

My textboxes gets rendered with name = "User.Firstname" etc

Thanks in advance
/m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passed in wrong class in post action